# Compiling source code of Kylin throws maven error

Tags: maven, kylin

I want to compile source code of Kylin and build it using Java 17 is that even possible?
I issue the following cmds:

1. git clone https://github.com/apache/kylin.git
2. mvn clean install -DskipTests

But the maven complains about:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project kylin-build-engine: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.kylin:kylin-build-engine:jar:4.0.3-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.7 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2/../lib/tools.jar

What could be a quick fix to this if I don't want to downgrade Java ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was how you got hold of the extra stuff in the JDK before Java 8.

It most likely requires an experienced programmer to update the sources to the new APIs and how they are packaged.

I would either get the expected version of Java or look for the newest version of the sources.